# How to unset action in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to change Top links structure. I don't want to mess with xml files in default theme. I have only one xml file with everything inside. I don't want to create multiple xml files in my theme layout folder. I am trying to unset action inside top.links block.

This is the way I am trying to do:

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="unsetChild"><child>addLink</child></action>
      <!--  <remove name="checkout_cart_link" /> -->
</reference>
```

When I put remove tag it works perfectly. But when I try to do unsetChild for addLink action it doesn't work. Do you know maybe how I should figure this out. I don't want separate xml files with the same names as in default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unsetChild` function is from the Abstract block model and is used for removing a block that is a child of the current block. The block with the name `top.links` doesn't have a child block that is called addLink, hence the fact your configuration doesn't do anything. The action nodes with the method `addLink` call the addLink function on the `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` block. If the objective is to remove one of the links, you will need to use the action `removeLinkByUrl`.

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>link/here</url></action>
</reference>
```

The exact arguments will obviously depend on what link you are attempting to remove.

Comment: And how would you remove this link, when there is no url set


<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way. One thing that we tend to do is overload the block to add helper methods for removing by it's name. You can find examples of that here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/435/#t260907

Comment: Cags, there is an easy way. I just want to let you know
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
</action>